# visualising websocket stream with streambuilder

Tags: flutter, websocket, flutter-streambuilder

currently working on an app that gives real time data visualization based on a thingsboard back-end.
I'm connecting to thingsboard over Websockets for which I first need to fetch a token from thingsboard.
this token let's me then set-up the websocket channel. Next up I send a JSON to the server by which I get a response. I'm using the websocket-channel package.
I've succeed in setting up the connecting, adding the request with sink.add and reading the response by channel.stream.listen.
However my question is now how can I visualize this data, incoming in the channel.stream.listen with i.e. the streambuilder widget?

```
class websocket_2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final int patientID;

  websocket_2(this.patientID);

  @override
  createState() => _websocket_2State(this.patientID);
}

class _websocket_2State extends State<websocket_2> {
  final int patientID;
  Patient patient = Patient.blank();
  List<dynamic> hranalys = [];
  //List<String> paramatt = [];
  late WebSocketChannel _paramWebsocket;
  late Stream<dynamic> stream = Stream.empty();

  _websocket_2State(this.patientID);

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('setchannel');
    stream = _setchannel();
    print('loadData');
    loadData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    closestream();
    super.dispose();
  }

  loadData() async {
    final patient = MockPatient.fetchByID(
        patientID); //await Patient.fetchByID(this.patientID);

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        this.patient = patient;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<String> getthingboardAPI() async {
    final check = await Token.requestMethod();
    print('$check');
    print('check token: ${check.token}');

    //Websocket credentials
    final String thingsBoardApiEndpoint =
        'wss://demo.thingsboard.io/api/ws/plugins/telemetry?token=${check.token}';
    print(thingsBoardApiEndpoint);

    return thingsBoardApiEndpoint;
  }

  Stream _setchannel() async* {
    /// Create the WebSocket channel
    print('creating WebSocket channel');
    WebSocketChannel channel =
        WebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse(await getthingboardAPI()));

    _sendstreamBody();
    _streamlisten();
    _paramWebsocket = channel;
    /*Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      print('opening stream');
    });*/
    stream = channel.stream;

    yield stream;
  }

  void _sendstreamBody() {
    var body = jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
      'tsSubCmds': [
        {
          'entityType': "DEVICE",
          'entityId': '5a36ce90-14ed-11ee-9079-75f587c23e37',
          'scope': "LATEST_TELEMETRY",
          'cmdId': '10'
        }
      ],
      'historyCmds': [],
      'attrSubCmds': []
    });
    print('body: $body');
    _paramWebsocket.sink.add(body);
  }

  void _streamlisten() async {
    stream.listen(
      (data) {
        //print('data:${data.data}');
        final Map<String, dynamic> itemMap = json.decode(data);
        var data_check = Parameters.fromJson(itemMap);
        print('${data_check.data['HR'][0][1]}');
        print('${data_check.data['RR'][0][1]}');
        print('${data_check.data['temp'][0][1]}');
      },
      onError: (error) => print(error),
    );
  }

  void closestream() {
    _paramWebsocket.sink.close();
  }
```

Token model and function to retrieve token:

```
@JsonSerializable(includeIfNull: false)
class Token {
  final String token;
  final String refreshToken;
  final String? scope;

  Token({required this.token, required this.refreshToken, required this.scope});

  factory Token.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$TokenFromJson(json);


static Future<Token> requestMethod() async {
//HTPP request to get JWT token
  var uri = Uri.parse('https://demo.thingsboard.io/api/auth/login');
  var body = jsonEncode(<String, String>{
    'username': 'gs@h3cares.be',
    'password': 'G94121827381s'
  });

  Map<String, String> headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  };

  final response = await http.post(uri, body: body, headers: headers);
  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  print(responseJson);

  final Map<String, dynamic> itemMap = json.decode(response.body);
  return Token.fromJson(itemMap);
}

}
```

Parameter model

```
@JsonSerializable(includeIfNull: false)
class Parameters {
  final int? subscriptionID;
  final int? errorCode;
  final String? errorMSG;
  final Map<String, dynamic> data;

  Parameters(
      {required this.subscriptionID,
      required this.errorCode,
      required this.errorMSG,
      required this.data});

  factory Parameters.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ParametersFromJson(json);
```

What I've tried you can see in the code above.